# There is only one analytic real function of a complex variable. Why am I wrong?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Consider a function $f: \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. As far as I know, for this function $f(x, y) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$ to be analytic, it must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann conditions, which state:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} 
$$

Of course, $v(x, y) = 0$. This implies that $u(x, y) = C$ where $C$ is constant, and thus the only real function of a complex variable is $f(z) = C$.

This cannot be right, surely? Why am I wrong?

Comment: Your proof looks fine to me. Why do you think it cannot be right? Being holomorphic is a much stricter property than just being smooth, and holomorphic functions often collapse to constants.

Comment: @paul blart math cop - I don't know, it just feels wrong. It's probably because the exercise I'm in the process of doing makes use of such a function, and this seems like too much of an easy way to solve it (the exercise in question has a whole load of extra qualifications on the function, and presumably wants me to reach the result I've reached above using these qualifications).

Comment: This is correct.  It might help your intuition to remember that analytic maps preserve angles except at critical points, and a map $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ would smush everything down to one dimension and so couldn't preserve angles.

Comment: lol, just reread the exercise and it never states that the function is analytic, oops. But thanks for the reassurance anyway.

Comment: A real function is is complex function where the imaginary part is constant.  To be analytic the the derivatives whether done "real part first" or "imaginary part first" must synch.  THis implies that we shouldn't *expect* analytic real functions to exist at all and the result that only the constant function applies really should not surprise us.

Comment: @jumbot   Just wanted to say I thought this was a great question -- one of those absolutely basic, fundamental things that nevertheless makes your head spin for a few moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is right! Here is a different proof: to say a function is holomorphic at a point $z_0$ is to say that the limit
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_0 + h) - f(z_0)}{h}
$$
exists where $h$ is approaching $0$ in the complex plane. If $f$ takes only real values, the quotient will be purely imaginary if $h$ approaches $0$ along the imaginary axis and purely real if $h$ approaches $0$ along the real axis, so for the limit to exist at $z_0$ the derivative must be zero and since $z_0$ was arbitrary, $f$ is constant.

What's going on here is that the condition that the limit has to exist when $h$ can be any complex number going to $0$ is much stronger than the analogous condition in real variables.

Comment: Good alternative explanation, thank you!